# Issue with Svn with Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, svn

I have to add my project in SVN, so I was installing SVN through help ->Install new Software's and Install [Svn by](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/latest-releases.php)

Actually it was not finding svn connectors:
`Window->Preferences->Team->SVN->SVN Connector`.

Here there is no svn connector available,so try to install it [from](http://www.polarion.com/products/svn/subversive/download.php?utm_source=eclipse.org&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=subversive)

But I get error during installation:

```
**An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/4.0/update-site/plugins/org.polarion.eclipse.team.svn.connector.svnkit16.sources_4.0.0.I20131101-1700.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/4.0/update-site/plugins/org.polarion.eclipse.team.svn.connector.svnkit17.sources_4.0.0.I20131101-1700.jar.
Read timed out
Unable to read repository at http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/4.0/update-site/plugins/org.polarion.eclipse.team.svn.connector.svnkit18.sources_4.0.0.I20131101-1700.jar.
Read timed out**
```

please help

Comment: If you edit a question to hide links behind text, please make it read as an English sentence -- it did read properly before the edit, not after the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try Subclipse? Link: http://subclipse.tigris.org/

I use it and never had an issue with it.

PS.: You should try changing the tag on the question since this has nothing to do with Android or the ADT plugin, it's just an Eclipse issue.